# Sympy.sqrt after sympify(string)

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, sympy

I have a problem with square root method in sympy. When I use the method *sympify(my_str)*, my program returns a value with sqrt:

```
>>> y = Symbol('y', positive=True)
>>> a = 'y**2'
>>> a = sympify(a)
>>> a
y**2
>>> a = sympy.sqrt(a)
>>> a
sqrt(y**2)
```

When I don't use the method *sympify(my_str)* my program returns the value expected:

```
>>> y = Symbol('y', positive=True)
>>> a = y**2
>>> a
y**2
>>> a = sympy.sqrt(a)
>>> a
y
```

How can I return the value desired (with sqrt) after I have sympified my string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [`sympify`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.sympify) function uses `eval`, the default `local` argument to the function is always set to `None`:

> Warning Note that this function uses eval, and thus shouldn’t be used
>   on unsanitized input.

If you want to `sympify` to gain access to already defined symbols, you can pass the `locals()` dictionary explicitly:

```
>>> a = 'y**2'
>>> a = sympy.sympify(a, locals=locals())
>>> a
y**2
>>> sympy.sqrt(a)
y
```

Or use a safer minified dict containing only the symbol(s) you need:

```
>>> a = 'y**2'
>>> a = sympy.sympify(a, locals={'y': y})
>>> sympy.sqrt(a)
y
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help